# JQuery Autotab Uppercase other than alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a code to convert all my input to uppercase. So far, the code provided in [here](https://github.com/Mathachew/jquery-autotab) doesn't provide a code for uppercase other than alphanumeric type. Basically, I want all type of input to be used in the `input[type=text]` to be converted to uppercase, not only the alphanumeric type one.

So far, I've wrote this but the input doesn't change to uppercase letters.

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('input[type=text]').autotab();
$('.all').autotab('filter', 'all', { format: 'custom', class:uppercase });
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="no_reg[1]" size="10" maxlength="6">
<input type="text" name="no_reg[2]" size="10" maxlength="8"> / 
<input type="text" name="no_reg[3]" size="10" maxlength="10">
```

p/s: I'm still new in jquery so I hope somebody can explain on this and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

To do this i used simply jquery toUpperCase function and for this example i used keyup event

```
<input type="text" name="no_reg[1]" size="10" maxlength="6">
<input type="text" name="no_reg[2]" size="10" maxlength="8"> 
<input type="text" name="no_reg[3]" size="10" maxlength="10">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg83M/2/)

Comment: I hope the codes are based on the Jquery Autotab codes that I provided in the link [here](https://github.com/Mathachew/jquery-autotab).

Comment: @user2781911 jQuery Autotab is built on jQuery platform, so all the built in jQuery functionality will be available.

Comment: @user2781911 See to acheive your task i dont think you want one more jquery plugin so that's why i did it with normal jquery plugin... and also no problem if you already have autotab simply replace this with that? it will work for sure

Comment: @HBK yeah but I didn't know how to adjust the code that convert it to uppercase so I hope someone can show me.

Comment: @Koushik If I replace my autotab code with your code, won't it only just convert the input to uppercase but not jump to another input like autotab did?

Comment: @user2781911 jQuery allows you to use result of one function to be an input to other. You can try $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
       // alert($(this).val().toUpperCase());
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    }).autotab();

Comment: did you replace the code separately..i think you mistake in that could you plz provide me jsfiddle..

Comment: @Koushik sorry i misunderstood your words. I just replace your code with mine that change it to uppercase which doesn't functional at all previously. And it worked! Just that, when the autotab is on, the last letter of the words in the input doesn't change to uppercase cuz the jquery is set in 'keyup'. The autotab will jump to the next input before I release the key. So I change it to 'keypress'. Furthermore, can you provide the code that change the sentences to uppercase when it is paste on? Together with 'keypress' function, cuz I need both to work.

Comment: there is a difference between keyup and keypress and after understanding you requirement i recommend you to go with change event coz in you case for every change the action is to be done... jsfiddle.net/Lg83M/9 ..